# A circle with the center at (1,3) has a radius of $2\sqrt{11}$. Find the difference between shaded region and unshaded region.

Tags: geometry

I've diagrammed it like this,
[image: The diagram that I made]

But then I got confused on what to do. I tried to dissect it into rectangles but that'll give me an approximation, not the valid answer (there's little arcs that area I didn't count) and I got the value of '12', which is supposedly the right answer for this question. Is there a right way to do it?

Comment: By "right way" I assume you mean only geometry (based on your tag)?

Comment: @DavidPeterson Umm, I mean, mine doesn't involve too much calculations. It's mostly based on the visuals, as this was originally a multiple-choice question.

Comment: @DavidPeterson So, I'm looking for a more elegant way to solve it. The first thing that came to mind for me is via geometry, but if there's a quicker way to solve it, I'd love to know!

Comment: The way to discount "12" is with $A=\pi r^2$. The shaded region is a bit more than half of the circle's area. This is in the neighborhood of $\dfrac{1}{2}\pi\cdot 44 \approx 70$

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind, I'm stupid. I just have to do this:
[image: Crosses cancels out]

The area with crosses cancels out each other, leaving only the central rectangle, which is the area difference...

Comment: Nice, missed the difference part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the area of three shapes: circular slices, rectangles, and triangles, you can cut the shaded area up into those.

For example, take the portion below (0,0). You can calculate its area by taking the circular slice centred at (1,3) with the endpoints (-x,0) and (0,-y), and subtracting off the two triangular additions (with a known base and height).

Triangles in red, rectangle in green. There's two remaining circular slices that I suck at drawing.

[image]